# Webdriver.io / wdio.conf.ts: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'mochaOpts' does not exist in type 'Config'

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm following the  [webdriver io typescript instructions](https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript.html)

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'mochaOpts' does not exist in type 'Config'.
```

This is due `wdio.conf.ts` including `mochaOpts` following:

```ts
import { Config } from "webdriverio";

const config: Config = {
  //...

  //
  // Options to be passed to Mocha.
  // See the full list at http://mochajs.org/
  mochaOpts: {
    ui: "bdd",
    timeout: 60000,
  },

//...

};

export { config };
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please share your typescript settings? I see you are using imports in the first line which does not work for me
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: @Stevy No idea if this is the right thing to do, but this is what I have - ```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,

    // NB expect-webdriverio seems to help with intellij view problems,
    // but still doesn't make tests run in intellij and is not recommended in docs
    "types": ["node", "webdriverio/sync", "expect-webdriverio", "@wdio/mocha-framework"]
  },
  "include": [
    "./test/**/**.ts",
    "./wdio.conf.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also add the `@wdio/mocha-framework` package.

However, the easiest way to configure everything for your setup would be to run `wdio init` in your terminal and follow the wizard.

If wdio seems not to be as a recognisable command you may need to use the relative path to it: `node_modules/.bin/wdio init`

NOTE: This assumes you have installed the Nodejs and the `webdriverio`, `wdio` packages.

Comment: In the end I found the problem with this - I had an extra `tsconfig.json` in a parent directory which was conflicting somehow I think. When I removed the additional `tsconfig.json` file, things seemed to work OK.